# How to move up and down in an int array

Tags: c#

I have the following array:

```
int[] month = new int[12] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
```

This represents my months in a year.

Now I have two buttons, and a label. The label should only display the value of the current item in the array. When I press, lets say, the next button, It should move from eg. 5 to 6 in the array, and now display 6 in the label.

Comment: So? What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I dont think you provide enough information. Is this winforms or wpf? How do you currently show values in your label?

Comment: I just want to move up and down inside the array. I can perform this with Java but not with c#.

Comment: @Bebbie7 Why not? The functionality for C# to do this and java to do this are virtually the same (if I remember correctly) so what exactly is the problem? month[5].ToString() would get you "6".....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code it will help you...

**Set this array as Global**

```
int[] month = new int[12] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
```

**Load event**

```
label1.Text = month[4].ToString();
```

**Next Button Click**

```
        int ind = Array.IndexOf<int>(month, Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text));
        if ((ind + 1) != 12)
            label1.Text = month[ind + 1].ToString();
        else
            MessageBox.Show("End of the Array element");
```

**Previous button Click**

```
            int ind = Array.IndexOf<int>(month, Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text));
            if ((ind - 1) != -1)
                label1.Text = month[ind - 1].ToString();
            else
                MessageBox.Show("End of the Array element");
```